# iOS in-app purchase not working with real account but working with sandbox

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I submitted new version of my app with in-app purchase added. App has been reviewed and is ready for sale. When I download app from store to device in-app purchase doesn't work. App doesn't do anything when buy/restore is clicked. No price is displayed.
Itunes connect in-app purchase status is:  Approved

With sandbox and the device everything works perfect.
It is my first app and maybe I forgot to do something.

Answer (score 1):

One possible thing is you missed to change the receipt verification URL of your receipt, If you are doing it in your app.

Sandbox URL

```
https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
```

Production URL

```
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
```

Comment: I'm not doing it in my app.

Comment: What happen when you purchase any product?

Comment: When IAP VC is displayed  I connect to store to retrieve app price. With sandbox I got price correctly but with real account there is no price displayed and no message from shop.

In my projest i have func failedTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("failedTransaction...")
        
        if transaction.error!.code != SKErrorCode.PaymentCancelled.rawValue {
            print("Transaction Error: \(transaction.error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }

but it works only with Xcode.